# Is there an a method to fit a wave created from two wave?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, python, scipy

I need to get the frequency and amplitude for a wave that consists of multiple function.
for example, if I have a sine curve (created from two sine waves), How can I extract the parameters for this complex wave.

I used the curve fitting code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42322656/9087140), as illustrated below. A simple sinusoidal function is used in the provided code. so I obtain a fitted curve with a single amplitude and frequency.

Data example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

x = np.arange(0, 50, 0.01)
x2 = np.arange(0, 100, 0.02)
x3 = np.arange(0, 150, 0.03)
sin1 = np.sin(x)
sin2 = np.sin(x2)
sin3= np.sin(x3/2)

sin4 = sin1 + sin2+sin3
plt.plot(x, sin4)
plt.show()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
import numpy, scipy.optimize

def fit_sin(tt, yy):
    '''Fit sin to the input time sequence, and return fitting parameters "amp", "omega", "phase", "offset", "freq", "period" and "fitfunc"'''
    tt = numpy.array(tt)
    yy = numpy.array(yy)
    ff = numpy.fft.fftfreq(len(tt), (tt[1]-tt[0]))   # assume uniform spacing
    Fyy = abs(numpy.fft.fft(yy))
    guess_freq = abs(ff[numpy.argmax(Fyy[1:])+1])   # excluding the zero frequency "peak", which is related to offset
    guess_amp = numpy.std(yy) * 2.**0.5
    guess_offset = numpy.mean(yy)
    guess = numpy.array([guess_amp, 2.*numpy.pi*guess_freq, 0., guess_offset])

    def sinfunc(t, A, w, p, c):  return A * numpy.sin(w*t + p) + c
    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(sinfunc, tt, yy, p0=guess)
    A, w, p, c = popt
    f = w/(2.*numpy.pi)
    fitfunc = lambda t: A * numpy.sin(w*t + p) + c
    return {"amp": A, "omega": w, "phase": p, "offset": c, "freq": f, "period": 1./f, "fitfunc": fitfunc, "maxcov": numpy.max(pcov), "rawres": (guess,popt,pcov)}

yy = sin4
tt = x
res = fit_sin(tt, yy)
print(str(i), "Amplitude=%(amp)s, Angular freq.=%(omega)s, phase=%(phase)s, offset=%(offset)s, Max. Cov.=%(maxcov)s" % res )
fit_values=res["fitfunc"](tt)
Frequenc_fit= res['freq']
print(i, Frequenc_fit)
Frequenc_fit=Frequenc_fit
Amp_fit=res['amp']
Omega_fit=res['omega']
Phase_fit=res['phase']
Offset_fit=res['offset']
maxcov_fit=res['maxcov']
plt.plot(tt, yy, "-k", label="y", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(tt,fit_values, "r-", label="y fit curve", linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

I got a fitted sine curve with a single frequency and amplitude as follows:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Is there a method to obtain fitted curve matches with the original one? or open software can be used to get the parameters for the best-fitted wave from the original one?
PLEASE, my understanding of FFT is VERY limited! So PLEASE forgive me for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: you mention [tag:fourier-transform] and [tag:fft]: what the FFT does is really take an input signal, and find the coefficients for complex sinusoids that when summed up, give the original signal. So, your problem is solved: you just need to properly draw all the resulting sines.

Comment: the FFT does that, as said above. It's literally what it does: it gives you the coefficients of all sines that when summed up give the original signal. You just need to pick the biggest two coefficient from one half of the result.

Comment: great, I will search for it. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

As a precautionary statement, the FFT will give you coefficients of the frequency components closest to the integer multiples of $1/T$ in Hz where $T$ is the length of the sequence in seconds being used for the FFT. If the components are not on these integer boundaries, then you will get several results (called spectral leakage) where the actual components (if information is known such as in the OP’s case of having just two tones) can be estimated as being in between two large adjacent results.

Further when combining the waveform you must pay attention to the phase as well as amplitude of the result in order for it to match the time domain waveform shown. The FFT will provide both a scaled magnitude and phase. The FFT results are the coefficients for complex frequencies (of the form $e^{j\omega t}$ but if it is known that the waveform is real then you can use the first half of the FFT as representing the coefficients of real frequencies in the form of $\cos(\omega t)$, scaled by $N/2$ where $N$ is the number of samples in the sequence used for the FFT.

Answer (score 1):

**I am not an expert on FFT and numerical modeling. I just tried to make an attempt since no one is answering the question. I used trial and error and gets an okay fit. I do not understand why I need to index in this way**

I tried to work with only two sin waves.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize

x = np.arange(0, 50, 0.01)
sin1 = np.sin(x)
sin2 = np.sin(2* x)
sin4 = sin1 + sin2
```

```py
tt = x
yy = sin4
n =  len(tt)

ff = np.fft.fftfreq(len(tt), (tt[1]-tt[0]))   # forier transform frequency assume uniform spacing
spectrum = np.fft.fft(yy) # contains complex numbers
magnitude = abs(spectrum) 
phase = np.angle(spectrum) 
amps = magnitude / n # I do not think this gives me the correct answer

# Find the index where the largest and second largest magnitude occurs. I reached this with trial and error, not really understanding how the index work for fft. Please someone help me explain why
wheremax = np.argmax(magnitude[1:]) # find where the maximum magnitude occurs
where2ndmax = np.argsort(magnitude[1:])[-3] # find the second largest magnitude (because of symmetry, I have to go further)

# Attempts to find the property of the waves. I do not think the amplitude and phase are correct
guess_freq1 = abs(ff[wheremax + 1]) # and find the dominant freq. I do not understand why + 1
guess_freq2 = abs(ff[where2ndmax + 1]) # find the second dominant freq
guess_amp1 = amps[wheremax + 1]
guess_amp2 = amps[where2ndmax + 1]
guess_phase1 = phase[wheremax + 1]
guess_phase2 = phase[where2ndmax + 1]
guess_offset = np.mean(yy)

guess = np.array([guess_amp1, guess_amp2, 2.*np.pi*guess_freq1, 2.*np.pi*guess_freq2, guess_phase1, guess_phase2, guess_offset])

# But with curve fitting, python managed to find the correct amplitude and phase or me
def sinfunc(t, A1, A2, w1, w2, p1, p2, c):  return A1 * np.sin(w1*t + p1) + A2 * np.sin(w2*t + p2) + c
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(sinfunc, tt, yy, p0=guess)
A1, A2, w1, w2, p1, p2, c = popt
fitfunc = lambda t: A1 * np.sin(w1*t + p1) + A2 * np.sin(w2*t + p2) + c 


# plot
x = tt
y = yy
x_pred = tt
y_pred = fitfunc(x_pred)

plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.plot(x_pred, y_pred, '-')
plt.show()
```

[image: fitting]

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone can edit my answer and explain fft more clearly

Comment: It seems you are missing a lot of things here. It seems that although you got some results, you don’t understand very basic things. Please don’t get me wrong this is absolutely OK, but I suggest you try and cover the basics first and then try to use them. I strongly suggest you look into the Discrete Fourier Transform - DFT - (FFT is just an efficient algorithm to calculate that) and then you’ll be able to understand what is that you have achieved with the code you provided. I don’t believe this answer provides too much insight into the solution and I believe needs supporting information here.

Comment: @ZaellixA Am I missing transforming real & imaginary numbers to sin phase and amplitude? [The two equations beneath eq.2?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) OR is there other things I might be missing? Can you edit my answer and pinpoint my mistakes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [pyestimate](https://github.com/alexishumblet/pyestimate) which implements fitting of multiple sinusoids. Two algorithms are implemented: non-linear least square and principal components auto-regressive estimator. Both are described in the book by Kay: *Fundamentals of statistical signal processing. Volume III, Practical algorithm development*.

Here is an example with 3 sinusoids:

```py
#!pip instal pyestimate
from pyestimate import multiple_sin_param_estimate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define a signal
n = np.arange(100)
s = 0.512 * np.cos(2*np.pi*0.123*n+np.pi/7) + 1.234 * np.cos(2*np.pi*0.0223*n+np.pi/2) + 2.123 * np.cos(2*np.pi*0.03*n+np.pi/9)
# add some noise
x = s + np.random.normal(scale=0.25, size=len(n))

# fit
A, f, phi = multiple_sin_param_estimate(x, 3)

# reconstruct signal
s_hat = 0
for i in range(len(A)):
    s_hat += A[i] * np.cos(2*np.pi*f[i]*n+phi[i])

# plot result
plt.plot(s, '-', label='original signal')
plt.plot(x, '.', label='noisy input data')
plt.plot(s_hat, 'r--', label='fitted signal')
plt.legend()
```

[image: Fitted sine result]